# Self-evaluation: let's get critical! — Que valons-nous?

Tags: discussion

We love our site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site (between 30 and 40 days old, to ensure that they have received enough attention without being too old to reflect the site as it is now). What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

For each question, search the Internet as if you were the asker. Are our answers better than the “competition”? Then vote up the corresponding answer here. Worse? Vote it down. About the same? Skip. Anything to remark? Comment.

[Rules and wording mostly lifted by [other](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374/computer-science-self-evaluation-lets-get-critical) [similar](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/909/evaluate-your-site-a-check-for-quality) evaluations by the Stack Exchange team.]

---

Nous aimons notre site, mais le reste du monde ne sait en général même pas qu'il existe. Le jour où ils le découvriront, leur première impression pourra être le dégoût ou le coup de foudre. Jaugeons donc la qualité des questions et des réponses et assurons-nous que le site offre ce qu'il y a de mieux.

Vous trouverez ci-dessous dix questions choisies au hasard (datant de 30 à 40 jours, pour assurer qu'il y a eu suffisamment de temps pour leur avoir consacré suffisamment d'attention sans pour autant être trop vieilles pour refléter le site tel qu'il est aujourd'hui). Que pensez-vous de chacune des questions et de ses réponses ? Sont-elles idéales, ou y a-t-il de la marge pour s'améliorer ? Un nouveau venu les trouverait-elles intéressantes et alléchantes, ou au contraire sont-elles embarrassantes ?

Pour chaque question, cherchez sur Internet comme si vous étiez le demandeur. Si nos réponses sont meilleurs que nos concurrents, plussoyez la réponse correspondante ici. Si elles sont moins bonnes, moinsoyez. Si elles sont de qualité semblables, passez à la suivante. Si vous avez des remarques, laissez un commentaire.

Comment: Thanks for [Anna Lear](http://french.stackexchange.com/users/774/anna-lear) for contributing the question selection methodology, to [Michael Mrozek](http://french.stackexchange.com/users/1251/michael-mrozek) for helping post the answers as the rate limiter let him, and to [Shog9](http://french.stackexchange.com/users/103/shog9) for revoking post ownership so that everyone (including me) can participate.

Comment: Fact is about half of our questions are original, ie I couldn't find other instances to compare. I guess it deserves an upvote.

Comment: @Evpok Yes, if there's no answer at all on the Internet (or in a basic dictionary), then we are better than the competition as a whole.

Comment: Je trouve ce forum très agréable. Son principal problème est qu'il génère peu de questions, car la plupart des questions de français que quelqu'un peut se poser trouvent leur réponse dans un dictionnaire bilingue ou dans le CNTRL. Et c'est aussi le cas d'une bonne moitié des questions ici présentes.

Answer (score 6):

[How to say ‘it’ when ‘it’ has no defined gender?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2614/how-to-say-it-when-it-has-no-defined-gender)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Que pensez-vous de cette question et de ses réponses ? Faites connaître votre opinion en votant et en commentant.

Comment: Un exemple typique de question qui semble demander quelque chose de général, mais cherche en fait à résoudre un problème précis, alors que la question générale était à mon avis plus intéressantes. Les réponses sont de meilleures qualité que la question.

Comment: La dernière partie de la question n'a pas reçu de réponse. On aurait du suggérer à l'auteur d'en faire une question séparée.

Comment: Même avis que Circeus.

Answer (score 5):

[How to translate “Be there or be square”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2603/how-to-translate-be-there-or-be-square)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Que pensez-vous de cette question et de ses réponses ? Faites connaître votre opinion en votant et en commentant.

Comment: Perso je n'aime pas particulièrement ce genre de question, mais Cédric fournit une excellente solution.

Comment: I like this kind of question, because Q&A is the only way to find an answer on the internet. With that said, translations aren't always the most interesting things you can come across...

Comment: Consultation de [reverso](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/be%20there%20or%20be%20square!) suffisait à avoir la réponse.

Comment: @Laure: Reverso ne donne que le sens de l'expression, sans que ça puisse véritablement servir de traduction. L'effet « sloggan » n'était pas préservé.

Answer (score 4):

[What is a good translation to "end up" somewhere?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/what-is-a-good-translation-to-end-up-somewhere)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Que pensez-vous de cette question et de ses réponses ? Faites connaître votre opinion en votant et en commentant.

Comment: Encore une question de traduction, mais avec beaucoup plus de solutions appropriées dans les réponses.

Comment: Réponse dans n'importe quel dictionnaire. Par exemple : [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/end%20up), [wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/end_up), [Reverso](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/end%20up).

Answer (score 4):

[Où est le « h aspiré » dans « anse » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/ou-est-le-h-aspire-dans-anse)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Que pensez-vous de cette question et de ses réponses ? Faites connaître votre opinion en votant et en commentant.

Comment: La question aurait méritée qu'on puisse l'explorer un peu mieux, mais il aurait probablement fallu un spécialiste pour aller plus loin que "c'est une variation dialectale".

Comment: Un coup d'œil au CNTRL donne une réponse sans ambiguïté.

Comment: Question intéressante et bien posée et qui mériterait encore d'autres réponses de façon à permettre de mieux cerner le phénomène. C'est le genre de question idéale pour FL&U où se rencontrent des francophones d'origines géographique variées.

Answer (score 2):

[« Et que cela saute ! »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2601/et-que-cela-saute)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Que pensez-vous de cette question et de ses réponses ? Faites connaître votre opinion en votant et en commentant.

Comment: Ah, les bonnes vieilles questions d'étymologies... appropriées, mais souvent difficiles, voire impossibles à répondre dans le cas des expressions.

Comment: Ici le sens suffit à donner l'origine de l'expression.

Answer (score 2):

[Is there any general rule to determine the gender of a noun based on its spelling?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2616/is-there-any-general-rule-to-determine-the-gender-of-a-noun-based-on-its-spellin)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Que pensez-vous de cette question et de ses réponses ? Faites connaître votre opinion en votant et en commentant.

Comment: Ahh... une superbe question... cauchermadesque à répondre, avec un vaillant effort, mais au final probablement pas très efficace.

Comment: Oui, bonne question, mais réponses peu concluantes je trouve. Et pour causes, les règles en ce domaines sont quasiment inexistantes.

Comment: On trouvait déjà la réponse sur internet à plusieurs endroits. Et Stéphane Gimenez a donné un lien vers une réponse convenant tout à fait à un anglophone.

Answer (score 1):

[For how long has French been the official language of France?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2597/for-how-long-has-french-been-the-official-language-of-france)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Que pensez-vous de cette question et de ses réponses ? Faites connaître votre opinion en votant et en commentant.

Comment: I didn't vote to close as off-topic but it was a near call.

Comment: Wikipedia est un meilleur point de départ pour ce genre de questions, même si la réponse est de bonne qualité.

Comment: La réponse se trouve facilement ailleurs.

Answer (score 1):

[Quelles sont les durées des mots utilisés dans les expressions ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/quelles-sont-les-durees-des-mots-utilises-dans-les-expressions)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Que pensez-vous de cette question et de ses réponses ? Faites connaître votre opinion en votant et en commentant.

Comment: Les réponses aurait probablement dû faire la part plus belle au fait que ce genre d'expression a rarement la précision présumée.

Comment: @Circeus, j'ai amélioré la réponse la plus complète avec cette information. L'édition des réponses par n'importe qui est quand même un aspect de SE.

Comment: Là aussi différents dictionnaires donnent la réponse sur internet et je ne vois pas l'intérêt de la poser sur stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

[What is the nickname for Michel?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2595/what-is-the-nickname-for-michel)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Que pensez-vous de cette question et de ses réponses ? Faites connaître votre opinion en votant et en commentant.

Comment: Le genre de questions qui causent problème parce que c'est souvent régional/entre petit groupe, mais des réponses bien pensées quand même.

Comment: Question a priori pas intéressante mais qui a apporté réponses et commentaires intéressants.

Answer (score -3):

[What is an effective word for not being attentive?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/what-is-an-effective-word-for-not-being-attentive)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Que pensez-vous de cette question et de ses réponses ? Faites connaître votre opinion en votant et en commentant.

Comment: Une question de traduction un peu simpliste, qui attire des réponses un peu simplistes, mais qui peux s'avérer utile pour qui... ne veut pas consulter un dictionnaire bilingue?

Comment: Là encore il suffit de consulter un dictionnaire en ligne pour trouver la réponse.