# Promotion de French Language — French Language promotion

Tags: discussion, area51, site-promotion

La fréquentation du site baisse et [nos statistiques sur area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language-usage) sont rouges dans deux catégories:

- 0.9 question par jour
- 416 visiteurs par jour

Dans le but de donner un coup de fouet à notre stack, quels seraient des moyens intéressant pour promouvoir le site et attirer plus des contributeurs? Quels sont nos points forts (voir à ce propos la question de Gilles : [Self-evaluation: let's get critical! — Que valons-nous?](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/self-evaluation-lets-get-critical-que-valons-nous))? Quelles seraient les meilleures stratégies pour pouvoir au mieux soutenir notre site?

---

Frequentation of the site is dropping and [our area51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language-usage) turned red for two points:

- 0.9 question per day
- 416 visitors per day

So as to kick off our stack, what would be the best promotion ideas to attract more contributors? What are our strenghts (see also Gilles' question : [Self-evaluation: let's get critical! — Que valons-nous?](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/self-evaluation-lets-get-critical-que-valons-nous))? What would be the best strategies to help us support our site?

Comment: je pense qu'il faudrait supprimer le mois d'aout du calendrier qui a fait perdre près d'une centaine de visite par jour... ;)

Comment: En effet, c'est repassé à l'orange depuis ce mois-ci!

Answer (score 3):

Ceci est un lien vers les questions et réponses qui ont été les plus visitées sur FL&U :

https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits

Je me disais que ça pourrait être intéressant de « fignoler » la présentation de ces questions et de leurs réponses, de façon à ce que les utilisateurs qui découvrent le site par ce biais soient plus enclins à lire d'autres questions, et peut-être même par la suite à participer !

---

Here is a link to the questions with the highest number of views on FL&U:

https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits

I thought it might be wise to “polish” these questions and answers a little bit, so that potential new users who discover the site reading these be more disposed to have a look at other questions, and maybe, later on, to participate!

Answer (score 3):

Comme ils disent sur [Chimie](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/what-can-i-do-for-this-site), et comme retransmis sur [Échecs](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/what-avenues-of-site-promotion-do-we-have-available) :

- Faisons savoir à tous les éventuels intéressés combien ce site est génial
- Amis bloggeurs, répandons la bonne parole, comme [là, par une modératrice de *The Workplace*](http://www.thickbook.com/2012/02/dear-stackexchange-will-you-be-my-valentine/)
- Motivons des experts à nous rejoindre
- Regazouillons¹ les questions d'[@StackFrench](http://twitter.com/StackFrench/)

---

<sup><sub>Si j'avais été malin, j'aurais adapté en anglais puis traduit, au lieu de recomposer en français et qu'il me faille retraduire. $hı†.</sub></sup>

¹ <sup><sub>[Bah quoi ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/4432/1514)</sub></sup>